# MSGraph request with $Filter returning Invalid Filter Clause

Tags: calendar, ms-office, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use a filter on a MSGraph CalendarView request.

The request works perfectly until I add the filter to the URL. After adding the filter I receive the error:

> "code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid filter clause"

The URL I am using for the quest is:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userEmail}/calendar/calendarView?$filter=subject contains 'twilight'&$top=1000&startDateTime=2022-04-25T00:00:00-04:00&endDate=2022-04-30T00:00:00-04:00](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserEmail%7D/calendar/calendarView?$filter=subject%20contains%20%27twilight%27&$top=1000&startDateTime=2022-04-25T00:00:00-04:00&endDate=2022-04-30T00:00:00-04:00)

I am trying to get any events with twilight in the subject between the date range.

Any ideas as I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains` method should be used this way:

`contains(subject, 'twilight')`

Instead `endDate` there should be `endDateTime`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userEmail}/calendar/calendarView? 
$filter=contains(subject,'twilight')&$top=1000
&startDateTime=2022-04-25T00:00:00-04:00&endDateTime=2022-04-30T00:00:00-04:00
```